# Illegal argument exception

Tags: java

When I enter a string that it not in the list, I get this error in my enum CrimeType

```
class: IllegalArgumentException, no enum const class CrimeType.a(in java.lang.Enum).
```

What does it mean and how can I fix this?

```
public void enterCrime()
{
    Crimes crimes = new Crimes();
    System.out.print("\t\tEnter crime: ");
    crimeName = In.nextLine();

    if("murder".equals(crimeName) || "arson".equals(crimeName) || "assault".equals(crimeName))
    {            
        crimes.daysToStay(3);        
    }
    else if("fraud".equals(crimeName) || "theft".equals(crimeName) || "vandalism".equals(crimeName))
    {
        crimes.daysToStay(2);
    }
    else if("drunk".equals(crimeName) || "littering".equals(crimeName) || "badHair".equals(crimeName))
    {
        crimes.daysToStay(1);
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("\t\tThat is not a valid crime. The crimes are");
        crimes.list();
    }      
    crimes.add(crimeName);
    enterAction();  
}
```

Enum Class

```
public enum CrimeType
{
    murder, arson, assault, fraud, theft, vandalism, drunk, littering, badHair;
}
```

Crimes Class

```
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;
public class Crimes
{
    private LinkedList<CrimeType> crimes = new LinkedList<CrimeType>();    

    public Crimes()
    {       
    }

    public void add(String crime)
    {
        CrimeType newCrime = CrimeType.valueOf(crime);
        crimes.add(newCrime);
    }
```

Comment: Didn't you just ask this a little while ago at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1417223/illegal-argument-exception

Comment: yes, but it wasn't answered and I figured if i asked it again with no answers in the thread, people will answer it, and it worked.

Comment: @dave: yes.  And one of the answers gave the root cause of the problem.

Comment: @Karen: Oh yes it did!  Go back and read them carefully.

Comment: Yes zlajo's answer gives the same reason as mine here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably should wrap your call to

```
CrimeType newCrime = CrimeType.valueOf(crime);
```

in a try/catch block.  This is where the code is failing.

Answer (score 4):

It means what you said in the first line "a string that it not in the list,"

CrimeType.valueOf(crime) will return a CrimeType matching the string crime.

[Javadoc for valueOf](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html#valueOf%28java.lang.Class,%20java.lang.String%29) says that if there is no constant with the specified name it will throw an IllegalArgumentException.

You then in the code have to decide what to do when the string does not match a enum.

First step to to enclose the valueOf in a try catch block and then in the catch do something could be print out that you have an unknown string or could do nothing or ...

Answer (score 1):

That is the expected behavior of calling [valueOf](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html#valueOf%28java.lang.Class,%20java.lang.String%29), when called with a string that is not defined in the enum.

Answer (score 1):

Your current problem lies in the fact that after determining the line entered *isn't* valid you still try to look it up... leading directly to the IllegalArgumentException.

However, as an aside, why have the extra logic anyway? The enum can quite happily contain the daysToStay data.

e.g.

```
public void enterCrime() {
    Crimes crimes = new Crimes();
    System.out.print("\t\tEnter crime: ");
    crimeName = In.nextLine();

    try { 
        crimes.add(crimeName);

    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        System.out.println("\t\tThat is not a valid crime. The crimes are");
        crimes.list();

    }      
    enterAction();  
}

public enum CrimeType {
    murder(3), arson(3), assault(3), 
    fraud(2), theft(2), vandalism(2), 
    drunk(1), littering(1), badHair(1);

    private final int daysToStay;

    CrimeType(in daysToStay) {
        this.daysToStay = daysToStay;
    }

    public int getDaysToStay() {
        return daysToStay;
    }
}
```